# Cannot assign sin_addr of sockaddr_in

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, winsock

I am using winsock2.h and trying to initialize sin_addr of sockaddr_in object.

```
sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_addr = INADDR_ANY; // ERROR C2679 there is no assignment operator
addr.sin_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0"); // Also ERROR C2679
```

Why? Every tutorial says to do like that, why isn't this working? How to initialize it?

Comment: See the example code here for how to assign using the member of the union - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sockaddr-2#example-code

Answer (score 3):

`inet_addr` returns a value of type `in_addr_t` which is basically a plain integer value.

The `sin_addr` member is a `struct in_addr`, which is not compatible with `in_addr_t` (despite the similar name).

But `struct in_Addr` has a `s_addr` member that can be assigned to:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(...);
```

If you check examples and tutorials a little closes then I'll bet that's  what you'll see.